# Which theorem is this? (Line Integral)

Tags: calculus, integration, continuity

I found this theorem in my Calculus book but I don't understand the proof really well.
I didn't find the name of the theorem so I can't find help on the internet.

> **Theorem:** Suppose that $f:[a,b]\times[c,d] \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Then the function
>
> \begin{align}
> I:[c,d] &\longrightarrow\, \mathbb{R}\\
> y\,\,\, &\longmapsto\, I(y) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y)\, dx
> \end{align}
>
> is continuous on the interval $[c,d]$.

Does someone knows the name of this theorem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt there is a theorem name for this. It's a fact that for any fixed $y$ that $f(x,y)$ is a continuous real valued function?

Comment: I don't know if the theorem has a name.  Its proof is a consequence of the fact that a continuous function on a closed domain is uniformly continuous there.

Comment: @Justin continuity of $f(\,\cdot\, y)$ for every $y$ alone is surely not enough.

Comment: @user251257, I agree that it is not enough

Comment: Isn't the integral of a continuous function also continuous? If so, maybe you could also use Fubini's Theorem to prove that.

Comment: @user251257, what is that black dot? There is that some black dot in the proof in our book

Comment: @AyoubRossi $g=f(\,\cdot\,,y)$ for a fixed $y\in[c,d]$ denotes a function $g$ which maps $x\in [a,b]$ to $g(x)=f(x,y)$.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks!

Comment: From what book do you have this? This does not have to do anything with line integrals.

Comment: It's the book that is given to us at the Vrije Universiteit brussel (Prof's book)